# Include creation time in managed property for SharePoint 2010

Tags: search, content-type

I've added a managed property "Created" and mapped it to Office:12 and Basic:15. It now displays the creation date of the documents.
However, I need the time as well. It only displays the date...

How can I include the time as well? Or, is the only way to create a new date/time column, set the value in ItemAdded and add that as a custom managed property?

Answer (score 0):

Hi why is office 12 being mapped? Is that for created date/time?

according to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134087(v=office.14).aspx Basic14 and Basic 15 should be a date/time and it is mapped to existing LastModifiedTime managed property.

Comment: I've found this out on other web blogs. It works, I see the created date, but not the created time.
Basic:16 maps to LastModifiedDateTime. Basic:15 maps to nothing yet.